# Vue - New Instance of Object as Attribute of Another New Object Not Nested

Tags: vue.js

I'm using Rails 5.2 with Vue.js 2 and I have the following object relationships...

- Menus

  - Entrees

    - Entree Options
  - Desserts

    - Dessert Options
  - Beverages

    - Beverage Options (attribute: food_item) // entree or dessert ID

menus has_many entrees, desserts, beverages
entrees has_many entree_options
desserts has_many dessert_options

I have a nested form for a menu.

Beverage options can be set for any of the built entrees or desserts (polymorphic). I need a way to grab the built entrees and desserts and associate the chosen one with the beverage_option object.

I can store the entire food_item object in Vue data and display the associated options as needed, but I can't figure out how to use v-model to associate the food_item with the beverage_option object since they aren't yet persisted and the beverage_options aren't directly nested under the food_items.

This is what I have now, which just results in a 'nil' value for food_item_id after the form is saved. If this isn't possible, is there a suggested way to handle this scenario in Vue?

```
        <div class="card mb-3">
          <h6 class="card-header">Beverages</h6>
          <div v-for="(beverage, index) in menu.beverages_attributes" :key="beverage.id">
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="card-text">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Name</label>
                  <input type="text" v-model="beverage.name" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <select class="custom-select" v-model="beverage.food_item_id">
                    <option>Choose One</option>
                    <option v-bind:value="food_item.id" v-for="food_item in menu.food_items" :key="food_item.id">
                      {{ food_item.name }}
                    </option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well yeah, the id will come from your db. Either save them in a temp variable and send that to api or generate a random id and then save.

When the api returns the response update with real ids.